# Setting up proxy for an axis ip camera in PHP

Tags: php, proxy, stream, ip-camera, mjpeg

I have been searching for a way to proxy a mjpeg stream from the AXIS M1114 Network Camera.

using the following url setup

```
http://host:port/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi?resolution=320x240&camera=1
```

i try to capture the output and make them available to users with a php script running an apache server on ubuntu.

having browsed the web looking for an answer to no avail i come to you.

my ultimate goal is to have users able to link to the proxy like this:

```
<img src='proxy.php'>
```

and have the details of all the things in proxy.php.

I have tried using the way of cURL (advised in similar thread here) but i can't get it to work, probably due to lack of knowledge on the inner workings.

currently my very simple proxy.php looks like this

```
<?php

    $camurl =   "http://ip:port";
    $campath =  "axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi";
    $userpass = "user:pw";  

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $camurl + $campath);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'resolution=320x240&camera=1');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $userpass);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    header('Content-type: image/jpeg'); 
    echo $result;           
    curl_close($ch);
?>
```

My understanding is that this would produce an acceptable output for my plan. But alas.

My question would be if there is a blatant error i do not see. Any simpler option/way of getting the result i aim for is welcome too.

Please point me in the right direction. I happily provide any relevant information i might have missed to provide. Thank you in advance.

solved edit:

After commenting out:

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

changing

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $camurl + $campath);
```

to

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $camurl . $campath);  (mixing up some languages)
```

and most importantly removing a space in the .php file so that the header is actually the header it sort of does what i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a

`curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);`

seems to be needed to get the image displayed as image and not as raw data.